# How to send a get form and receive the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, curl

Okay I am actually working as a pentester for a company i found that there's an error in there website which they generate csrf tokens due to get request to this page `localhost/csrf-token` and give out the csrf tokens in unencrypted text
To get the right csrf token the cookies of the user need to be sent with the request 
I tried using curl in my POC to get the result of the request which is the token
but the cookies wasn't sent with the request
I found out that the only way that the request might get sent into is using a normal form but i can't get its result 
The curl code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://localhost/csrf-token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
));
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $output;
```

The normal get request that I want to use is

```
<form action="localhost/csrf-token" method="get">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

my question here is how to get the result of the second code snippet

Comment: First of all: Your text is very hard to read. Please use some punctuation, it greatly increases the chance people are willing to help you.

As for your question: copy the headline of your question into a google search field and find the answer. If that does not help, let us know what the problem is.

Comment: I was using new lines , but the website removed them. Furthermore, of course i searched google and didn't find anything useful

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'parametsr');
```

use this to add parameters.

As your form can send only one parameter.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://localhost/csrf-token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'submit=send');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
));
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $output;
```

will be the request with form. 
Or just change URL as your request is GET

```
https://localhost/csrf-token?submit=send
```

However, i think the request will also require cookies to generate token.

Comment: I still need to send in cookies from the user as a type of csrf attack so I will need the second code snippet which is in html but I also need the response the form parmeter isn't important

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm saying ..as curl operates on server their are no cookies appended to the request .. Hence, it will not generate token for you. The url will return token only if the request is made from a cookie enabled browser or cookies are manually appended to the request.